# Unable to login to cloudbees from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, cloudbees

I am trying to get eclipse to work with CloudBees. I can login to CloudBees on their website but not from eclipse.

```
Window -> Preferences -> CloudBees
```

My login info is correct but I get the following error when I press 'Validate'

```
Failed to get account services info.
invalid number or unquoted string near L><HEAD><TITLE>Error Message</TITLE>
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: invalid number or unquoted string near L><HEAD><TITLE>Error Message</TITLE>
```

All the latest versions are installed as of 01 Feb 2014.

```
Eclipse Platform (Kepler) 4.3.1.v20130911-1000
Cloudbees Toolkit 2.0.2.201307232010
Subclipse 1.10.3
Eclipse EGit 3.2.0.2013121281205-r
```

Thanks

Ken

Comment: I am using the same version of Kepler and CloudBees toolkit (I do not use any scm plugin, though) and for me it's working. Do you have any "weird character" in your mail/password?

Comment: Do you have anything in your Eclipse error log? Are you able to capture network traffic and see exactly what goes down the wire?

Comment: @valentina Hi Robert, I can log in successfully from home so the office firewall must be getting in the way. I will attempt to capture the traffic as you suggest.